# iCloud Keychain encryption

Tags: icloud, security, password, keychain, encryption

I have a question about the strength of the iCloud Keychain encryption key.

I know that when I enable iCloud Keychain sync on my device, Apple encrypts my local keychain and stores it on their servers. They use end-to-end encryption and data is encrypted on the device and can not be read by Apple.

What key does Apple use to encrypt the Keychain? From official documentation [link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202303) and third-party articles [link](https://www.macworld.com/article/3603954/why-icloud-keychain-may-prompt-you-for-a-device-password-used-with-other-apple-hardware-you-own.html), it seems that they use a key derived only from my device passcode which is a very short and weak 4-digits string.  It means that in case someone was able to break into Apple servers and steal the data it can easily brute force it and reveal the content since it's only protected with encryption with 10^4 of entropy.
BTW, the same applies to the encrypted IOS backup that they store on iCloud.

Please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: Please add the links to the official documentation and third-party articles you are referring to.

Comment: You're not wrong, but using a 4-digit passcode is rather limiting since you can always specify a much more complex passcode for the encryption, and then use Touch ID to unlock.

Comment: @nohillside thx, added.

Comment: @IconDaemon Thanks for your confirmation.